# How to fetch vCenter version using API?

Tags: vcenter, pyvmomi

I want to fetch the vCenter version for my project using API, tried with the pyvmomi python library.
But I could not the vCenter version, eventhough I'm able to get ESXi and VM related information.

[Version info in the vCenter UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJeDl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect

con = SmartConnect(host="172.1.1.1", user="", pwd='')

print(con.RetrieveContent().about.version)





(vim.AboutInfo) {
  dynamicType = <unset>,
  dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
  name = 'VMware vCenter Server',
  fullName = 'VMware vCenter Server 6.7.0 build-18485185',
  vendor = 'VMware, Inc.',
  version = '6.7.0',
  build = '18485185',
  localeVersion = 'INTL',
  localeBuild = '000',
  osType = 'linux-x64',
  productLineId = 'vpx',
  apiType = 'VirtualCenter',
  apiVersion = '6.7.3',
  instanceUuid = '1f7fc3f0-2b79-4f99-8d0a-44be5fdf2021',
  licenseProductName = 'VMware VirtualCenter Server',
  licenseProductVersion = '6.0'
}
```